# Is there a way to search across all scripts in a deployment?

Tags: powershell, octopus-deploy

I have a PowerShell script module in a deployment, which defines a function that seems to be going wrong.  Unfortunately, because it's in a script module, I don't know where the call to it is coming from, and it's a very large and complicated deploy with many steps.

Is there any way to run a text search for the name of this function across all scripts used in the entire deployment?

Comment: I don't follow. Are you trying to just list all functions in your*.psm1/*.psd1 file then match on a function name?

Comment: @postanote You know how, if you go into a deployment step that's defined as a script, you can get into the text of the script and run a search on it?  I'm looking for a way in the Octopus HTML UI to run that text search over *all* the scripts in the entire deploy, much like how, in Visual Studio, I can run a text search over all the code files in my project.

Comment: Ah OK, that's why I gave the first comment. The samples, that I've now removed were just approaches since I was not clear.  I've personally never used or seen anything dealing with Octopus, so I cannot comment on it. OK, that being said, time to look up Octopus HTML UI to get the whys/wherefores of it. It's been a very long time since I've had to mess with all up Visual Studio but, yep that I understand and have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using inline scripts in your deployment process you can download the entire process to a JSON file, via the overflow menu on the process edit page.

The script body for each step is contained within the property:

`Octopus.Action.Script.ScriptBody`.

If you are using scripts sourced from packages you will need to check in your source repositories for references to the script module function, the JSON for the step will contain the following properties:

```
"Octopus.Action.Script.ScriptSource": "Package",
"Octopus.Action.Script.ScriptFileName": "script1.ps1",
"Octopus.Action.Package.PackageId": "packageId",
```